# Does same image implies the same preimage?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Assume $A_0$ and $A_1$ are two subsets of $A$.

If $f(A_0)= f(A_1)$ for some function $f: A \to B$, can we conclude that $f^{-1}f(A_0)=f^{-1}f(A_1)$, so that $A_0 = A_1$? Thanks!!

Comment: Of course, we get $f ^{-1}(f(A_0))=f^ {-1}(f(A_1))$. But that does not imply $A_0=A_1$.

Comment: Thanks! Is it because f might not be an injective function?

Comment: Yes, try using the definition of injective that "f(a) = f(b) implies a = b" to show this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A$ be a grocery store.

Let $A_0$ and $A_1$ be two bowls of fruit on display in the store.

$A_0$ contains cherries and oranges.
$A_1$ contains strawberries, pomegranates, and oranges.

Let $f$ be the function that takes a fruit and tells you what color it is.